# Is sombrero an english word?

Tags: loan-words

A coworker told me that the word "sombrero" is an English word borrowed from Mexico. I had the idea is a foreign word. Is that right?

Comment: A quote from James Nicoll seems appropriate here: ***[English doesn't] just borrow words; on occasion, English has pursued other languages down alleyways to beat them unconscious and rifle their pockets for new vocabulary.*** You're both correct; *sombrero* is a Spanish word that has been "borrowed" into the southwestern regional dialect of English via Mexico. You will rarely hear it used in areas where the particular style of hat is not commonly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a foreign word, but it is also an English word - it is a word that has been borrowed into English (a "loanword") and has now become an accepted part of English vocabulary.  It's found in English dictionaries (for example, [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sombrero)).

By contrast, you are unlikely to find the word "chien" (French for "dog") in an English dictionary, because it hasn't been borrowed into English, isn't widely used by English speakers and isn't an English word.

Comment: As a footnote, just about [**every**](https://onelook.com/?w=sombrero&ls=a) English dictionary lists this word, not just Oxford.